# A word for design that is clear and does not need to be explained

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, in a videogame where the level teaches you a game mechanic through level design rather than telling you, or a device that doesn't need instructions because the design clearly shows you how it works.

I thought the word was "innovative" but that's not quite right it seems, as that's more to do with coming up with new ideas.

Example:

> Super Mario 3D Land has _____ level design, as it teaches you through playing the level instead of relying on tutorials or trial and error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Intuitive** design would be something where the user could immediately *intuit* how or what to do without explanation.

Related, but doesn't quite fit, would be "invisible" design, where the design of something is so ideal that it's hard to imagine it any other way.

Comment: Thank you! That's why I thought it sounded like innovative...

Answer (score 2):

You can use ***self-explanatory***.

> : easy to understand without explanation
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self%E2%80%93explanatory)</sub>